# Help identifying this viney plant in Oregon

Tags: shrubs, vines, fall-gardening

I would like to relocate this plant in my yard, but I can’t seem to find any roots or how to pull it up. If I knew what it was called then I could probably figure out how to move it.

[image]

Comment: Clearer photos of the leaves and stem structure would be helpful in identifying the plant, and any observations about its flowers, fruits, or behavior throughout the year. I did a quick search and came up with Myoporum parvifolium, but I'm not sure that's what you're looking at.